# How do I launch unicorn_rails as a startup script with rvm installed on my ubuntu 12.04 machine?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ruby-on-rails, unicorn

I have a rails app on my server. I have a script startup.sh which launches unicorn_rails and then nginx.

In order to get my server to launch on system boot, I've added a line to call my startup script to /etc/rc.local

However, this doesn't work. I added some checks to make sure the script is being called and it is. It's the call to unicorn_rails which I think is failing. Does anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a user-permission issue. Unicorn, ruby and rails were installed as my regular login while the script was being launched as the root user. This created issues with the gems installed not being visible to the root user. I solved the problem by calling a second script with 'su' as my regular non-root user.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and I was able to resolve my issue by creating an init.d script for unicorn_rails and then enabling it on startup with chkconfig.

```
chmod +x /etc/init.d/unicorn
chkconfig unicorn on
```

Example unicorn_rails init.d script.  https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/blob/master/contrib/unicorn_init.sh

The only major change I made in my script was to add nginx service calls to the action blocks.  This way when you start/stop/restart or run status on unicorn_rails nginx follows suit.